# clear string from commas and put it into array

Tags: php

I want clear all commas from string and then put all words separated with comma into array.

For me it's easy to make it in the case i have this type of string:

```
word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6
```

I have juste to explode them and put them into array like this:

```
$words = "word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6";
$explode = explode(",", $words);

$array = array();
foreach($explode as $word) {
  $array[] = $word;
}
```

And here come my need: 
In the case i have this kind of string what is the approch ?

```
word1,,word2,,,word3,word4,,,,,,,,,,,,word5,,,,word6...
```

The number of commas between words undefined and can be up to 100 commas.

Let me know if u have good approch to this kind of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function in PHP is used for "filtering" an array i.e. making a new array from the elements of an array that satisfy a condition.

By default if we do not pass any callback to array_filter, it removes all falsey and null values. We can send a callback function as a second parameter which returns true for elements that should stay and false for elements that should be removed.

```
$words = "word1,word2,word3,word4,word5,word6";
$words_arr = array_filter(explode(",", $words));
print_r($words_arr);
```

If there is whitespace between commas, then:

```
$words_arr = array_filter(explode(",", $words), function ($e) {
    return strlen(trim($e)) > 0;    // Only select those elements which have a length > 0 after trimming
});
```

[strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is for getting the string length

[trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is for stripping whitespace from the beginning and end of a string

Comment: First thank's for the solution, and what if there whitespaces between commas ?

Answer (score 2):

use preg_split

```
$explode = preg_split("/,+/", $words);
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `explode` as you did to get all the values:

```
>>> $values = explode(',', 'word1,word2,,,,word3');
>>> print_r($values);
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word2
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
    [4] =>
    [5] => word3
)
```

Use `array_filter` on the solution to filter out empty results:

```
>>> $non_empty_values = array_filter($values);
>>> print_r($non_empty_values);
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word2
    [5] => word3
)
```

Finally, to reset the array indices, use `array_values`:

```
>>> $results = array_values($non_empty_values);
>>> print_r($results)
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word2
    [2] => word3
)
```